# Can a SELECT statement block an ALTER TABLE?

Tags: postgresql, migration, locking, blocking

I see in [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html):

> Two transactions cannot hold locks of conflicting modes on the same table at the same time

During maintenance (schema migration) we saw cases when we can't `ALTER TABLE` because of hanging `SELECT` in transaction (`pg_locks` + `pg_stat_activity`).

In order to proceed migration we revoke `CONNECT` from "rogue" users and kicked all their sessions.

Is that correct that:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ...;
```

will block `ALTER TABLE` until `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: Totally, that's what the docs tell you, too.  And the first lock will be there until it's released (of these locks that means end of the transaction), the 'stronger' ones won't kick the weaker ones.

Comment: Thanks for stronger/weaker. That's what I misunderstood without prior experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right.

This is how PostgreSQL prevents conflicts: you cannot drop or modify a table while someone is using it.

Answer (score 0):

yes , in Mysql SELECT itself is considered a transaction.
so if one transaction is on a table , you can not  get meta data lock for alter.